# The value of $P\bigl(|X-Y|>6\bigr)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $(X,Y)$ be two dimensional random variable such that $E(X)=E(Y)=3$ & $var(X)=var(Y)=1$ & $cov(X,Y)=\dfrac{1}{2}$. Then , $P(|X-Y|>6)$ is :

(a) less than $\dfrac{1}{6}$

(b) equal to $\dfrac{1}{2}$

(c) equal to $\dfrac{1}{3}$

(d) greater than $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

$\mathcal My$ $\mathcal Attempt :$

> First suppose that, $Z=X-Y$. Then from the given conditions we compute $E(XY)=\dfrac{19}{2}$ & $E\bigl(X^{2}\bigr)=E\bigl(Y^{2}\bigr)=10$. Then compute mean of $Z\bigl(i.e. m_{z} \bigr)$ & variance $\bigl(\sigma_{z}^{2}\bigr)$. We get, $m_{z}=0$ & $\sigma_{z}^{2}=1$.
>
> Thus we get, $Z$ is $N(0,1)$ variate. We have to find $P\bigl(|Z|>6\bigr)$.
>
> Now from the distribution of $Z$ how we can find out the required probability or we conclude any one of the given four options ?
>
> I also tried through $Tchebycheff's$ inequality but I can not apply it.

Comment: unless $X$ and $Y$ are normal, you cannot conclude that $X$ is.

Comment: Are $X,Y$ normal?

Comment: I suggest using the Chebyshev Inequality, although it is very pessimistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is clearly (a).

You can discard the "equals" right away - these is not enough information for such a strong conclusion.

You can discard (d) because a random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$ cannot be so far away from $0$ half the time.

You can use [Chebyshev Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) to actually prove (a):

$$ P(|Z|>6\sigma_Z)\le \frac{1}{6^2} $$

since $\sigma_Z=1$, we get

$$ P(|Z|>6)\le \frac{1}{36} < \frac{1}{6} $$

Comment: But Tchebycheff's inequality is $P\bigl(|X-m| \ge \epsilon \bigr)\le \dfrac{\sigma^{2}}{\epsilon^{2}}$.

Comment: your version is equivalent to mine (identical in this case of $m=0$ and $\sigma=1$